# Button that enrolls students for a course and leads to the enrollment form

Tags: actions

I have an *actions.yml* file with the following content.

```yaml
student_enrollment.enroll_course:  
  route_name: student_enrollment.enroll  
  route_parameters:  
    course_id: 1  
  title: Enroll  
  appears_on:  
    - entity.node.canonical
```

This is a button located in /node/{node_id}.

How can I make the *course_id* route parameter dynamic so that when the node ID is for example 5, course_id will be 5 too?

This actually is a button for enroll students in a course. When the enrollment button is clicked, students should be redirected to the enrollment form shown in the student_enrollment.enroll route.

This is the definition for that route.

```yaml
student_enrollment.enroll:  
  path: '/enroll/{course_id}'  
  defaults:  
    _title: 'Enroll for the course'  
    _form: 'Drupal\student_enrollment\Form\StudentEnrollmentForm'  
  requirements:  
    _permission: 'enroll for a course'  
  options:  
    parameters:  
      course_id: \d+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add "class" parameter in mymodule.links.actions.yml file

```
class: 'Drupal\student_enrollment\Plugin\Menu\LocalAction\EnrollCourseAddLocalAction
```

Complete code : mymodule.links.actions.yml

```
student_enrollment.enroll_course:  
  route_name: student_enrollment.enroll  
  title: Enroll  
  appears_on:  
    - entity.node.canonical
  class: 'Drupal\student_enrollment\Plugin\Menu\LocalAction\EnrollCourseAddLocalAction'
```

Create: EnrollCourseAddLocalAction.php file in this folder:
src/Plugin/Menu/LocalAction

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\student_enrollment\Plugin\Menu\LocalAction;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalActionDefault;

/**
 * Modifies the local action to set value of dynamic parameter course_id.
 */
class EnrollCourseAddLocalAction extends LocalActionDefault {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRouteParameters(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // Here you use parameter that you are getting from route it can be course_id/nid/id
  // Added get course id from node object
    $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $course_id = $node->id();
    }
    return ['course_id' => $course_id];
  }

}
```

Comment: But it gives me The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "course_id" for route "student_enrollment.enroll" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL. in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 209 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

Comment: @Danail Sapunjiev , This issue replicate due to course id parameter not exist so I updated code like this  : $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $course_id = $node->id();
    }
you can check updated code